# Pretty printing type of values in llvm pass

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I am trying to print the type and name of the values used inside a loop as follows:

```
(value->getType())->print(COUT);
errs() << "     type: " << COUT.str() << " ";
errs() << "     name: " << (value->getName()) << "\n";
```

I get the following output:

```
type: i32*      name: sum
type: [25 x %struct.Book]*      name: books
```

Is it possible to pretty print the type in the way they are used in program? For instance, get something like as:

```
type: int      name: sum
type: struct Book      name: books
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own function. For an example, see the original function [`TypePrinting::print`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/AsmWriter_8cpp_source.html#l00446).

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be done. There is no guaranteed mapping between LLVM name and source name; there may be no source type that corresponds to a given LLVM type, or several.

You could only even attempt this given detailed knowledge of how a *specific* frontend converts source types into LLVM types. Even then, it would be solely within the limitations of that scheme- for example, my frontend creates GUID names for types and functions.